# django app in cpaned doesn't upload pictures that I upload from django admistration page

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

after I deployed my django app to cpanel it doesn't save pictures that I upload it from django adminstration page

Not: all data I enter it's save it and can return it to template but pictures not upload them

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, in models you should use,

```
your_variable_name = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
```

and if this solution doesn't work, try posting your code here.